# Find angle x in a circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

Can we find $x$ here? Because I think the data given is insufficient.

[image]

Comment: I would indeed say that the problem definition is lacking.

Comment: There are four segments and one circle.  Call the lines a,b,c d is clockwise order.  a is from where the x is labled to where the 38 is labeled.  b goes from 30 to the center, c from the cent to the edge.  And d from the edge back to the x.  Leave a and be exactly as the are but nudge c backword from 7'ocloc to, say 6:31.   d will hae to change too but leave a and be exactly as the are.  The angle marked 38 willl still be 38.  Buthe angle marked x will be smaller.  Both have the same information.  So it is impossible to solve.

Comment: Reminds me of [this meme](https://www.memecenter.com/fun/160/Find-x), and it's legitimate to do so in this case :)

Comment: Note: within the quadrilateral the angle at $O$ is $360-2x$ and the angle at the bottom is therefore $x-38$. So you cannot solve for $x$ unless there is extra information not noted in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not enough information to make the calculation. Just move the two bottom sides left (ish)/right (ish) as allowed. Then it becomes evident why.

[image]

Comment: What if all the points are unmoveable/constant?

Comment: Then there must be a single answer, but we will not be able to get it without further measurements. There is nothing stopping the situation above from being the same as the situation in your picture, as far as the measurements tell us.

Answer (score 0):

Data is definitely insufficient. Visualize the angle x as the bottom point (of the quadrilateral inside the circle) travels along the circle. It's not constant, but each place for the point is totally valid for the problem. So there's not a definite answer.

Comment: What if it is constant?

Comment: @BillPham If the bottom point were constant, it would be solvable. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: I mean what if all the points in the original shape are constant?

Comment: Well, all the points being constant implies that the bottom point is constant. Also, the other points are already constant - the center of the circle is fixed, the top point is just the end of an arbitrary radius, and with the given angle the point $x$ is fixed. So the bottom point is the only one that isn't constant.